# Simple search on CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my Controller

```
public function search()
{
    $this->load->model('student_model')
    $keyword = $this->input->post('search');
    $student = $this->student_model->search($keyword);
    $this->load->view('result',$student);
}
```

This my model

```
function search($keyword){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('data', ['nisn' => $this->input->get('nisn')])->row();
    return $query;
}
```

Form view

```
<form class="margin-bottom-small" method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('student/search/') ?>"> 
            <p> NISN</p>
            <input type="text" name="search">
            <input type="submit">   
        </form>
```

Somehow i just wanted to show

```
<?php echo $student->nisn;?>
<?php echo $student->name;?>
<?php echo $student->class;?>
```

But when i tried it always not work
it keep says syntax error, unexpected '$keyword' (T_VARIABLE)
Cant help it been trying the one on internet and it not work too

Answer (score 1):

Add `;` after `$this->load->model('student_model')`

```
public function search()
{
    $this->load->model('student_model');
    $keyword = $this->input->post('search');
    $student = $this->student_model->search($keyword);
    $data['student']= $student;
    $this->load->view('result',$data);
}
```

Comment: oh yup i forgot that
but when it change now it be Message: Undefined variable: student

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you have some mistakes here are:

- Semicolon (;) is required after:

  ```
  $this->load->model('student_model');
  ```
- You must convert this chunk into valid Array format:

  ```
  array('nisn' => $this->input->get('nisn'));
  ```

**Tip:** When you face some of T_VARIABLE errors in PHP, it is recommended to check the lines before the line shown in the error itself.

**For your knowledge:** Please have a look at 
[List of Parser Tokens](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) !

Answer (score 0):

I think this little change in your modelfuntion will fix the problem

```
    function search($keyword){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('tablename', ['field' => $keyword])->row();
    return $query;
}
```

so in your case,code will be like this

```
function search($keyword){
        $query = $this->db->get_where('data', ['nisn' => $keyword])->row();
        return $query;
    }
```